# Nested Knockout.js templates not working in IE9

Tags: knockout.js

I have created a fiddle to test this :

http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjanoel/X6ShS/

which works fine :(

I am basically creating everything in that fiddle inside a 'facebox' popup, html and javascript passed from the server as JSON, and then written to the contents of the facebox.

My problem is that on the confirmation screen, the template inside the template is not working in IE9. I cant test in any other version of IE just yet, and Firefox and opera work fine, and even, as I say, IE works with the fiddle I created.

Can anyone suggest how I might go about fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some invalid markup, it shows up in jsfiddle in red.

```
<script type="text/html" id="conf-ltt-ln-bx">
    <div class="hl_lottolinebox confirm">
         <span data-bind="text: $data.n" class="hl_lotteryNumber" maxlength="2"/>
         <span>
    </div>
</script>
```

Fixing the above made it work in IE9 for me.

Hope this helps.